# »Im Gras verstecken« oder »in das Gras verstecken«?

Tags: preposition, grammatical-case

> Die Eltern verstecken die Eier im Gras.

Der Satz ist richtig. Aber ich habe gedacht, dass man „in das Gras“ schreiben sollte, weil „verstecken“ eine Bewegung ist.
Aber warum schreibt man „im Gras“?

Comment: Nein, entscheide Dich für eine der Fragen und mach aus der anderen eine neue. Immer nur eine Frage, denn sonst kann man mit den SE-Tools nicht sagen, ob sie beantwortet ist, wer die beste Antwort gegeben hat, die Diskussion zerfleddert - eine geht weiter, während die andere beeendet ist usw.

Comment: Mache bitte zwei Fragen daraus... Dann kann man beide recht einfach beantworten. So wie es ist, wird es geschlossen werden, weil man nicht weiss, welche der beiden Fragen Du beantwortet haben willst...

Comment: I removed the second question. Please create a new question to address the second issue.

Comment: Ich wusste es nicht. Entschuldigung.

Answer (score 8):

*Verstecken* steht mit Dativ, denn man versteckt eine Sache *an einem Ort*. Die Frage ist also, *wo* etwas versteckt ist und nicht *wohin*.

Answer (score 4):

### Erstens

Wenn ein Verb eine Bewegung ausdrückt, muss das dazugehörige Objekt keineswegs das Ziel der Bewegung angeben.

Das ist zwar durchaus völlig in Ordnung:

> Ich fahre mit dem Auto in die Stadt.
>   Ich fahre mit dem Fahrrad in das Dorf.

Das bedeutet: Man befindet anfangs außerhalb der Ortschaft und gelangt durch die Bewegung in diese hinein.

Aber auch das ist ebenso ok:

> Ich fahre mit dem Auto in der Stadt.
>   Ich fahre mit dem Fahrrad im Dorf.

Das bedeutet: Man befindet sich während der gesamten Bewegung, also von Anfang an, in der Ortschaft und verlässt sie nicht. Man bewegt sich innerhalb der Ortschaft.

### Zweitens

Was veranlasst dich anzunehmen, das Verb »verstecken« drücke eine Bewegung aus? Das ist nämlich nicht der Fall. Dieses Verb gehört vielmehr zu jenen Verben, die ausdrücken, dass etwas an einen Ort gebracht wurde, um dort einige Zeit zu ruhen und um eventuell später wieder von dort entfernt zu werden. Im Fokus der Bedeutung stehen aber weder das Hinbringen noch das Wegnehmen, sondern das Verharren an einem Ort. Vergleichbare Verben sind:

- lagern
- deponieren
- aufbewahren

> Die Betreiber lagern die Brennstäbe im Bergwerk. (nicht »in das Bergwerk«)
>   Umweltsünder deponierten den Müll im Wald. (nicht »in den Wald«)
>   Meine Mutter bewahrt die Vorräte im roten Behälter auf. (nicht »in den .. Behälter«)
>   Die Eltern verstecken die Eier im Gras. (nicht »in das Gras«)

Comment: Als Ergänzung - Obacht: es gibt auch das Verb *einlagern*. Dieses drückt allerdings sowohl den Vorgang als auch den Zustand aus und steht dann mit Akkusativ oder Dativ. Beispiele: *Ich lagere den Gegenstand in das Lagerfach XYZ ein* oder *Wir haben unsere Sommerreifen im Autohaus eingelagert.*.

Answer (score 3):

Vorsicht vor übertragener Bedeutung!

Das Verb "stecken" drückt eine gerichtete Bewegung aus und nimmt daher wie üblich den Akkusativ. ("Stecken Sie sich ihre Vorschriften *an den Hut*!)

Das Verb "verstecken" hat aber meistens nicht die kompositionale Bedeutung von ver- + stecken ("an den falschen Ort stecken"), sondern übertragene Bedeutung "an einen *unbekannten* Ort stecken". Damit wird es verwendet wie z.B. "aufbewahren": im Fokus der Aussage steht der *Ort*, an dem die Sache verbleibt, nicht die Bewegung, mit der sie dort hingebracht wird. Und Ortsangaben verwenden normalerweise den Dativ.